# Convert MDDYYYY and MMDDYYYY column to MM-DD-YYYY in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g, to-char

I used `SELECT TO_DATE(INC_DATE, 'MMDDYYYY') FROM BASICINCIDENT2010;`but since not all the dates in the inc_date are of the same format. It causes the error of Month not found.

Comment: I'm not positive I know what your question is. Maybe provide some data and what you want the output to be.

Comment: @MattCremeens I think more important is the source data than output data.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a `CASE` statement to decode the date strings differently.  Something like the following:

```
CASE
    WHEN LENGTH(inc_date) =  7 THEN TO_DATE(inc_date,  'MDDYYYY')
    WHEN LENGTH(inc_date) =  8 THEN TO_DATE(inc_date, 'MMDDYYYY')
    ELSE TO_DATE(inc_date, 'MM-DD-YYYY')
END AS fixed_date
```